# Close Python Selenium 's command line window after it runs using Window Batch

Tags: python, selenium, batch-file, command-line

I use Python Selenium to do Web scraping, trigger it using a batch .bat file. The chrome browser and the command line window still open after it runs successfully. It should be closed because I put exit at the end of the batch script. see below code

```
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
"C:/Users/h/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe" "C:/Users/h/Desktop/Bbq/Python/Test.py"
timeout /t 12 /nobreak
exit
```

I look at the message in the cmd, here's the screenshot
[image]

I wonder if any of the errors cause the problem? please advise.

Comment: you have an odd expectation of what the `Exit` command does, which is: `Quits the CMD.EXE program (command interpreter) or the current batch
script.`. It has no bearing on any programs you run from within a batch script or command window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this exception to bypass all error, and force the brower to quit

```
import traceback.

try:
    print(abcd)
except :
    print(traceback.format_exc())

    print("ERROR")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```